# In SQL Server, is there a way to pivot on an unknown number columns WITHOUT using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

Essentially if we have this:

```
create table #temp ([key] nchar, [value] nvarchar(2));
insert #temp ([key], [value]) values
             ('a',   '1'),
             ('b',   '2'),
             ...
             ('z',   '26')
```

the goal would be to get a string back that looks like this:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2",..."z":"26"}
```

The problem here is that the count - and names - of the columns are both unknown.  Now, there are ways to do this using `PIVOT` with dynamic SQL, but in general, dynamic SQL can be prone to injection if you're just using it with a bunch of random data.  On Stack Overflow and on this site, I see some questions with answers posted that use this combination, but they either don't mention injection or make a claim that it's immune to injection, which I'm a little uneasy about.

So...is there any way to do this without a dynamic query in SQL Server?  SQL injection isn't always immediate; sometimes the injected code sits dormant inside of tables, waiting to be used in dynamic SQL queries.  How can you do this *without* using dynamic SQL - or failing that, is there at least truly a way that's not vulnerable to injection?

---

Two notes, in response to the comments:

#1: As far as whether `PIVOT` is used or not goes, all I'm really wanting to do, in my personal case, is to switch rows and columns and create a JSON object out of it.  I have a table that looks somewhat similar to the above, which is being used, at least in one case, to store keys and values out of a C# dictionary.  However when using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, I need it to look like this:

```
{
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
    ...
}
```

not like this:

```
[{
    "Key": "Key1",
    "Value": "Value1",
}, {
    "Key": "Key2",
    "Value": "Value2"
}, {
    ...
}]
```

For certain reasons, I want this transformation to be made in SQL, if possible.

#2: The concern with SQL injection is this: When you concatenate values, if one of the values has a `whatever'; SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable; --` type of script in it, even if the script wasn't run when it was originally inserted (because of good use of SQL parameters and precautions like that), it can still be run later if it's just concatenated blindly into a dynamic SQL query.

I will have to change my mind and just deal with this in C#, if that can't be perfectly guarded against.  I can't really assume the data doesn't have something crazy like that in there, so I'm not comfortable concatenating it into something that's run, unless there's a truly safe way (more than just escaping ticks) to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a single string back, you don't need `PIVOT`, and you don't need to dynamically determine column names. Assuming SQL Server 2017 or better:

```
;WITH x(y) AS 
(
  SELECT QUOTENAME([key], '"') + ':' + QUOTENAME([value], '"')
  FROM #temp
)
SELECT output = N'{' + STRING_AGG(y, ',') + '}' FROM x;
```

- Example on SQL Server 2017: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1b32b20eb695ef5eeebef679824db81)

The columns defined in the question were limited to a max of 2 characters, but if you might have more, as Charlieface pointed out, `QUOTENAME()` is limited to 128 characters. In that case you'll want something a little safer, again assuming SQL Server 2017 or better:

```
;WITH x(y) AS 
(
  SELECT '"' + STRING_ESCAPE([key],   'json') + '":"' 
             + STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json') + '"'
  FROM #temp
)
SELECT output = N'{' + STRING_AGG(y, ',') + '}' FROM x;
```

- Example using `STRING_ESCAPE()`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=28eda486a9227e834cd510a975d35a07)

If you're on an older version of SQL Server, you can use the less efficient and more cumbersome `FOR XML PATH` (and I'll leave escaping unsafe JSON characters using `REPLACE` as an exercise for the reader):

```
;WITH x(y) AS 
(
  SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([key], '"') + ':' + QUOTENAME([value], '"')
  FROM #temp
)
SELECT output = N'{' + STUFF(
    (SELECT y FROM x FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value
    (N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + '}';
```

- Example on SQL Server 2014: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=63a35953aad945d30e84bc8710d6df41)

As for protecting yourself from SQL injection, I wrote a couple of posts on that:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/)